# How do I perform an iterative calculation using a value from another table selected based on a YYYY-MM date and write it back to the first table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, relational

Started learning PHP and MySQL yesterday and have managed to create two tables, insert rows and then display that data on a web page using various different groupings. Now I need to do a calculation based on data in the two tables and write the result back to one of the tables.

I'm trying to figure out how to perform an equation for a row with a date in table A using a range of values associated with a range of dates in table B. The two dates are in the format YYYY-MM-DD, but the days mostly do not match, so I need match on the month.

Here's the two tables I have:

Table A (user)

```
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
| id | username | start-date | bench-value |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | tim      | 2010-03-04 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  2 | jim      | 2010-05-30 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  3 | fred     | 2010-06-12 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  4 | sam      | 2010-08-16 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  5 | jane     | 2010-10-21 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  6 | ella     | 2010-10-21 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  7 | bob      | 2011-01-24 |             |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Table B (benchmark)

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | start-date |  value  |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2010-01-31 | 1173.19 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  2 | 2010-02-28 | 1199.85 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  3 | 2010-03-31 | 1264.91 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  4 | 2010-04-30 | 1263.43 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  5 | 2010-05-31 | 1211.36 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  6 | 2010-06-30 | 1187.32 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  7 | 2010-07-31 | 1218.30 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  8 | 2010-08-31 | 1207.96 |
+----+------------+---------+
|  9 | 2010-09-30 | 1272.12 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 10 | 2010-10-31 | 1280.27 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 11 | 2010-11-30 | 1275.60 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 12 | 2010-12-31 | 1346.45 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 13 | 2011-01-31 | 1337.07 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 14 | 2011-02-28 | 1338.37 |
+----+------------+---------+
| 15 | 2011-03-31 | 1349.14 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

And here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

tim's current bench value today = the sum of: (first(benchmark.value)/latest(benchmark.value))for every month from the first to the latest month inclusive
First date  = 2010-03 which is id  3 = 1264.91
Latest date = 2011-03 which is id 15 = 1349.14 (this is always the last row as I am trying to calculate on "today" and nothing in the future)

```
1/(first/latest)   =1/(1264.91/1349.14) = 1.0666    [this is bench.id=3]
...now iterate...
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1263.43/1349.14) = 1.0678    [bench.id=4]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1211.36/1349.14) = 1.1137    [bench.id=5]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1187.32/1349.14) = 1.1363    [bench.id=6]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1218.30/1349.14) = 1.1074    [bench.id=7]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1207.96/1349.14) = 1.1169    [bench.id=8]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1272.12/1349.14) = 1.0605    [bench.id=9]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1280.27/1349.14) = 1.0538    [bench.id=10]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1275.60/1349.14) = 1.0577    [bench.id=11]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1346.45/1349.14) = 1.0020    [bench.id=12]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1337.07/1349.14) = 1.0090    [bench.id=13]
1/(next/latest)    =1/(1338.37/1349.14) = 1.0080    [bench.id=14]
...and finish up...
1/(current/latest) =1/(1349.14/1349.14) = 1.0000    [bench.id=15]

Total = 13.7997 = 1.0666 + 1.0678 + 1.1137 + 1.1363 + 1.1074 + 1.1169 + 1.0605 + 1.0538 + 1.0577 + 1.002 + 1.009 + 1.008 + 1
```

So I would then want to write that result back to Table A, giving me:

Table A (user)

```
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
| id | username | start-date | bench-value |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | tim      | 2010-03-04 |     13.7997 |
+----+----------+------------+-------------+
```

As this is an iterative process it would be a much shorter calculation for a user like 'bob' who started in 2011-01.

I would also like to be able to do this every 4 months to produce termly stats so that someone like user tim would be calculated like this (the initial search to find the first date would need to take into account over a 4 month period):

```
1/(first/latest)   = 2010-03 = 1/(1264.91/1349.14) = 1.0666
1/(next/latest)    = 2010-07 = 1/(1218.30/1349.14) = 1.1074
1/(next/latest)    = 2010-11 = 1/(1275.60/1349.14) = 1.0577
1/(current/latest) = 2011-03 = 1/(1349.14/1349.14) = 1.0000

Total = 1.0666 + 1.1074 + 1.0577 + 1 = 4.2317
```

That major issues I'm having are two fold:
1. how to use the user.start-date value for each user to pick the first(benchmark.value) based ont he year and the month (day is unimportant).
2. how to iteratively calculate the formula up to and including the latest value in the bench table - at the end of april, a new row with id=16 would be added and if this were run then the April value would become the last value used in the calculation.

As I'm learning SQL And PHP right now I'm not sure which parts of this process should be done in SQL and which in PHP.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated as I'm determined to figure this out.

That major issues I'm having are two fold:

1. how to use the user.start-date value
   for each user to pick the
   first(benchmark.value) based on the
   year and the month (day is
   unimportant).
2. how to iteratively calculate the
   formula up to and including the
   latest value in the bench table - at
   the end of april, a new row with
   id=16 would be added and if this
   were run then the April value would
   become the last value used in the
   calculation.

As I'm learning SQL And PHP right now I'm not sure which parts of this process should be done in SQL and which in PHP.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated as I'm determined to figure this out.

Just for reference, I've been reading:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html
- http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_2191631_3/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables.htm
- There were more but it won't let me post the other links yet...

There's almost too much info out there, so some guided advice would be realy appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't include the column bench-value in table A. This value will be constantly changing, so it would be better to create a View that would calculate the latest User bench-value or create a stored procedure that takes a User as a parameter and then returns the bench-value

There also needs to be a link/key between the two tables, right now there is no way to tell which user is related to which benchmark

Comment: The link between the two tables is the date. These benchmark values are calculated on each user each time this is run (every month). I like the idea of creating a new table that gets updated with the bench-value and an id that matches the user - that's a really good idea, thanks.

Comment: @lukescammell in your example for Tim you only show 4 records associated with him. Shouldn't it be id 3 to id 15?

Comment: in my example for Tim I wrote _"I would also like to be able to do this every 4 months to produce termly stats"_ so the benchmark value only gets calculated every 4 month, ie. you don't do it monthly, you do it once every 4 months, or 3 times a year if you prefer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what a well asked question. Sadly my reply maybe a lot shorter.

What I think you're looking for is:

> bob's current bench value today = the
>   sum of:
>   first(benchmark.value)/latest(benchmark.value)
>   First date = 2011-01 which is id 13 =
>   1337.07 Latest date = 2011-03 which is id 15 = 1349.14

```
select username, start_date, tmp.value/tmp2.value as new_mark from tablea
 join (select id,value from tableb having id=min(id) group by id) as tmp
 on tablea.id=tmp.id 
join  (select id,value from tableb having id=max(id) group by id) as tmp2 
on tablea.id=tmp2.id
```

That seems ugly but should work.

Comment: Wow, what a complex answer! well, for a 30 hour SQL newbie :D I shall now try and figure that out and apply it directly... thanks!

Comment: In short it creates tmp which is a list of values for the first date by person, tmp2 which is the values for the last date, and then works the calculation and spits out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, does that include intermediary dates as well?

Comment: No, thats not what you asked for. your question was first and latest. If you just wanted an average for a time period, it would actually be a lot simpler.

Comment: Oh and as someone else pointed out, you have 2 ID fields, but it also doesnt show that ID in the "tableb" doesnt repeat, ergo its just a unique number so how do you tell which is whos data?

Comment: Hmm, I think I maybe haven't asked my question very well in that case. I'll try and reword it using tim as the example as he has a longer history than bob.

I'm just using the id column as a unique identifier for each row, the ids aren't actually related to each other.  The two tables are related to each other by date, nothing else. Let me reword the initial example and see if I can be clearer. I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: I have just edited the original question using 'tim' as the example to hopefully more clearly show that I'm trying to iterate through all months between the start-date for each user and the current date, today. Thanks.

Comment: The only problem is, you still have 2 tables 1 with incremental IDs for people, the other just incremental IDs, for each mark. Nothing truly demonstrates how you relate the two. Initially I assumed the ID column in tableB was the ID of the person.. Is this the case?

Comment: The two tables are only related by date, the id in each table is just an unique id for that particular table - perhaps I should just get rid of the id columns?! They only seem to be confusing the issue here and I'm not actually using them for anything at the moment. Would the meaning be clearer if I just removed both id columns?

Comment: So, in your first table when you have 2 people with the same date, does the same mark really apply to both?

Comment: I think I've asked too many things at once here. I need to go back to the drawing board and break it down into little steps and come at each step in turn. Thanks for spending your time on this, it's actually really helped me even in just this realisation. What's the SO etiquette here? Can this question be closed/deleted? I don't think it should go any further in its current state. Thanks again! :)